# comparing one dictionary with array of dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I want to add or remove a dictionary on the array based on two cases.
For example,
Let us create a array of dictionary,

```
var Result=[{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3},{'d':4}];
```

Let us consider two cases,
Case-1:
An input dictionary that has both the same key and value which is in the Result variable.

```
input={'c':3}
```

then the result should be,

```
 var Result=[{'a':1},{'b':2},{'d':4}];
```

Case-2:
An input dictionary that has the same key and different value(input1) and vice versa(input2) or both different key and value(input3) which the Result variable array have.

```
input1={'d':6}
input2={'x':3}
input3={'e':10}
```

then the result should be,

```
var Result=[{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3},{'d':4},{'d':6},{'x':3},{'e':10}];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some code. What did you already try to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: do you want to mutate `Result`?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes,Since im new to js and jquery cant sort.Help me to sort out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the index of the given key/value pair and remove this item of the array or push the object to the array.

This approach mutates the array.

```js
function update(array, object) {
    var [key, value] = Object.entries(object)[0],
        index = array.findIndex(o => o[key] === value);

    if (index === -1) {
        array.push(object);
    } else {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

var array = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }, { d: 4 }],
    input1 = { c: 3 },
    input2 = { d: 6 };

update(array, input1),
console.log(array);

update(array, input2);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered but i enjoyed the task. 
Here is my working.

The logic is to combine both `Arrays` and if there is a `key:value` duplicate then ignore otherwise populate.

```js
const INIT = [{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3},{'d':4}];

const input1 = {'c':3}
const input2 = {'d':6}
const input3 = {'x':3}
const input4 = {'e':10}

const INPUTS = [input1, input2, input3, input4]

const merge_and_de_dupe = (dictionary, overwrite) => {
  const combined = [...dictionary, ...overwrite]
  
  return combined.reduce((prev, curr, i, orig) => {
    const [item_key, item_value] = Object.entries(curr)[0]

    const all_duplicates = orig.filter(oI => item_key in oI && oI[item_key] === item_value)
    
    return all_duplicates.length > 1 ? prev : [...prev, curr]
  }, [])
}

const stripped = merge_and_de_dupe(INIT, INPUTS)

console.log(stripped)
```

Comment: Thanks ,I need one more help,Can u give me the keys and values in a separate separate array@FrancisLeigh Please help me

Comment: @Venugopalsrinivasan the keys and values of the `stripped` Array in their own arrays?